# call response.redirect from inner div of a page to load a new page onto the browser

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I'm loading a some page content to an inner div called 'center_column'  in my index.jsp using ajax load method.

```
$('#center_column').load('abc.jsp', function() {    });
```

but while it is loading I want to check for the session time out and redirect the request to login page. This session time out code is in within the 'abc.jsp'

I used

```
response.sendRedirect("login.html");
```

method for it. But this will reload the login.html with in the **#center_column** div.

But I want to load login.html onto the browser instead of the existing page ( index.jsp) on the browser. And also I want to fix this without using javascript.

Can anyone guide me to solve this issue please

Thanks

Comment: Fixing AJAX problems without JavaScript is not possible. The J in AJAX means JavaScript. You're ruling out the only possible solution.

Comment: What I mean by without javascript is, I want to have a server side solution for this instead of using javascript function calls in index.jsp to reload the login.html.

Comment: And as I said, you can't solve that at server-side. The only way is to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript, but it's minimal.  Try handling your session check on the server like this:

```
if (request.getSession(false) == null) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    return;
}
```

Then in your callback function on the client side,

```
$('#center_column').load('abc.jsp', function(responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 403)
        window.location = '/login.html';
});
```